# Store value selected in drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu, which is part of an update function for this program my teacher asked me to do.

http://oi39.tinypic.com/sboec6.jpg

The options are Age, First Name, Last Name (sorry for non-english).

HTML Code

```
<br><p><br>Atualizar (Insira o primeiro nome):</p>
<input name="primeiro_nome_selecionado" placeholder="" autofocus>
<select name="a_modificar">
<option value="idade_modificar">Idade (a idade para a qual deseja mudar):</option>
<option value="primeiro_nome_modificar">Primeiro nome (o nome para o qual deseja mudar):</option>
<option value="ultimo_nome_modificar">Ultimo nome (o apelido para o qual deseja mudar):</option>
</select>   
<input name="valor_a_modificar" placeholder="Valor a inserir:" autofocus>
<input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
```

PHP Code

```
if($primeiro_nome = '$primeiro_nome_selecionado'){


if($a_modificar = '$primeiro_nome_modificar'){ 
mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET primeiro_nome='$valor_a_modificar' WHERE primeiro_nome='$primeiro_nome_selecionado'");
}

if($a_modificar = '$ultimo_nome_modificar'){
mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET ultimo_nome='$valor_a_modificar' WHERE primeiro_nome='$primeiro_nome_selecionado'");
}

if($a_modificar = '$idade_modificar'){
mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET idade='$valor_a_modificar' WHERE primeiro_nome='$primeiro_nome_selecionado'");
}
```

My problem:

Regardless of whether I select Age, First or Last name on the dropdown menu, the new_value you can see in the first screenshot, is always inserted in the first_name field of the table.

http://oi40.tinypic.com/e6dg5f.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single `=` instead of `==`

Also you are wrapping your variables in apostrophes which won't work

```
if($a_modificar == $primeiro_nome_modificar){ 
  mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET primeiro_nome='$valor_a_modificar' WHERE primeiro_nome='$primeiro_nome_selecionado'");
}

if($a_modificar == $ultimo_nome_modificar){
  mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET ultimo_nome='$valor_a_modificar' WHERE primeiro_nome='$primeiro_nome_selecionado'");
}

if($a_modificar == $idade_modificar){
  mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET idade='$valor_a_modificar' WHERE primeiro_nome='$primeiro_nome_selecionado'");
}
```

And what is the

```
if($primeiro_nome = '$primeiro_nome_selecionado'){
```

doing? Seems unclosed

Comment: All the other 3 ifs are inside that one, I forgot to copy/paste it here, thanks

Comment: Also, you might be confusing the language or something, those ' are required otherwise it won't even replace anything.

Comment: I mean these apostrophes `if($a_modificar = '$primeiro_nome_modificar')`

Comment: The other ones should look like this: `mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET primeiro_nome='" . mysql_real_escape_string($valor_a_modificar) ."' WHERE primeiro_nome='". mysql_real_escape_string($primeiro_nome_selecionado) ."'");
`

Comment: Still only edits the "First Name" field, regardless of what I select in the drop down menu. Thanks for answering